# I have release version 10 debian and am trying to run steam on it. How can I best do this?

Tags: debian

I have several problems running steam on this computer. For starters, whenever I try to run a command (such as sudo: add-apt-repository) it says sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found. I'm very confused, other instances of this occuring are as follows:

Attempts to find the universe/multiverse end in "error: 'universe/multiverse' invalid"

attempts to run dkpg also end in it being called invalid, soecifically as sudo: dkpg: command not found

I've tried to look through the top results for similar questions and couldn't find any that matched my question (Though there were a lot, so I might've missed one-- I apologize if I did.) Do you know what's going on?

Comment: 1. "universe" is an ubuntu repo, not debian.  Don't install ubuntu packages on debian. 1a. I guess you just read some random blog posts and blindly followed the instructions on them.  don't do that. 2. You don't need to add a repo, the steam client is in the `steam` is in the non-free section of debian.

Comment: Got it, sorry, I won't do that in the future. Can you tell me the specific command? I am very very dumb.